# Como hacer que un código .jsp pueda leer un código de un .java para hacer un UPDATE a la base de datos

Tags: java, html5, base-de-datos, jsp

Lo manejo con servlets, jsp y java. Aqui les dejo mi [Github](https://github.com/dmd9210/guardias) con todo el código.

Intento hacer un update a una base de datos en base a .jsp o la manera más fácil que me arroje una forma de registro para hacer solamente el update.

Esta imagen les muestra como la tengo la idea, que a la hora que le de click pueda editar lo que esta en la tabla.

[image: Imagen de UPDATE]

También les dejo como tengo el código del UPDATE :

```
public void updateCliente (Cliente cliente){
    try{
        statement = 
        connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE cliente SET usuario=?,password=?,nombre=?,apellidoP=?,apellidoM,tel=?,email=?,tipodePersona=?,descripcion=?,rfc=?,WHERE idCliente=?"); 
            synchronized(statement){
                statement.setString(1,cliente.getusuario());
                statement.setString(2,cliente.getpassword());
                statement.setString(3,cliente.getnombre());
                statement.setString(4,cliente.getapellidoP());
                statement.setString(5,cliente.getapellidoM());
                statement.setString(6,cliente.gettel());
                statement.setString(7,cliente.getemail());
                statement.setString(8,cliente.gettipodePersona());
                statement.setString(9,cliente.getdescripcion());
                statement.setString(10,cliente.getrfc());
                statement.setString(11,cliente.getidCliente());
                statement.executeUpdate();
                }
                statement.close();
                } catch(SQLException sqle){
                    logger.log( Level.SEVERE, 
                        sqle.toString(),sqle);
                    throw new
                    RuntimeException(sqle);
                }
}
```

---

Los problemas que me han presentado es que no puedo realizar el update porque quiero saber si puedo redrigir a jsp a un anchor tag o también un enlace a otro servlet.

Gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: No pongas enlaces a tu código, en su lugar coloca en tu pregunta el código que veas necesario para que se pueda reproducir el problema

Comment: no coloques tu correo puesto que los usuarios te pueden dar solución por este medio cuyo cual fue hecho para formular preguntas y dar soluciones acá mismo y brinden ayudas a otro con las mismas dudas.

Comment: La pregunta es muy vaga ya que no explicas qué haces y qué problemas te has encontrado. En todo caso tu SQL tiene una coma `,` de más delante del `WHERE`.

Comment: SJuan ahí puse en la parte de abajo a lo que intento hacer para poder resolver de alguna manera.

Comment: Tu problema es que no sabes como llamar a tu método update a través de una .jsp?

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo tu pregunta ¿tienes un servlet y lo llamas en el jsp y quieres que el servlet ejecute un .java ?.

el jsp ya de por si puede ejecutar codigo en java, importa la clase en el archivo, por ejemplo `<%@page import="com.ejemplo.ejemploupdate"%>`.

y ya puedes llamar los metodos en cualquier parte del html agregando

```
<%
%>
```

Comment: Como ejecutas en el jsp un update para poder actualizar la base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

No se debe llamar directamente desde un JSP a BBDD. Te recomiendo montarte un servicio REST con Jersey que a través de jQuery o la api js que quieras envie a servicio web los datos y este a su vez llame al código que tu quieras después de validar los datos.